# Сервер Minecraft. Java потребляет больше максимально заданной ОЗУ

Tags: java

Создал Сервер Minecraft на VDS.(поскольку не обладаю особыми знаниями, закончилось это не очень хорошо)

При перезапуске виртуальной машины и первом запуске сервера - сервер ест всего 1.3 GB ОЗУ, что прекрасно, однако со временем ситуация ухудшается.
При перезапуске самого сервера(без перезапуска виртуальной машины, а при помощи команд /stop и ./run.sh) , использование оперативной памяти подскакивает до 3GB, что странно.

**При длительной работе сервера Java начинает потреблять память предназначенную под систему, в итоге сервер падает.**

Для запуска я использую файл .sh, в котором прописано следующее.

```
java -Xms1G -Xmx3G -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:G1NewSizePercent=30 -XX:G1MaxNewSizePercent=40 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=8M -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:G1HeapWastePercent=5 -XX:G1MixedGCCountTarget=8 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=15 -XX:G1MixedGCLiveThresholdPercent=90 -XX:G1RSetUpdatingPauseTimePercent=5 -XX:SurvivorRatio=32 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1 -Dusing.aikars.flags=”https://mcflags.emc.gs” -Daikars.new.flags=true -jar server.jar nogui
```

В данный момент изменил значения -Xms на 512M, -Xmx на 1 GB, в надежде, что что-либо изменится.

Характеристики VDS, на котором всё это дело и стоит:
4GB RAM, 4 ядра 1Ghz, 90 gb hdd.
OS Ubuntu 16.04

Количество одновременно находящихся на сервере игроков не превышает 5.

Версия сервера Minecraft 20w16a.